# systemd mounting conditions

Tags: systemd, mount

I'd like to mount a file system during boot on host A, but only when service X is running on host B.

Is it doable in systemd without creating artificial rc.local like service?

Comment: How is A aware of the fact that X is running on host B ?

Comment: Do you have a mechanism of detecting whether that other service runs? What kind of service are we considering?